# Customize a new runlevel for single user

Tags: debian, virtual-machine, qemu, runlevel

I try to open FreeDOS by QEMU on Debian and I don't want the user can switch to Debian.
In graphical mode, I can't find a proper method to do this. There are some display problem, like console size cannot fit the fullscreen.
Then, I found that in single user mode, freeDOS can fit my goal with command "qemu-system-x86_64 -smp cores=8 --enable-kvm -m 2048 -nographic -hda FreeDOS.img":

1. No other tty consoles
2. User can't switch back to debian.
3. FreeDOS displays in fullscreen.

But in single user mode, it seems that it can't auto-login and ca't auto-start the FreeDOS by qemu command.
So, I think maybe I could create a new runlevel for this.
Is this possible?

Comment: runlevels are not made for such things. It is just a way to order scripts for system administrators: there is no enforcement. But so, you are asking a lot of unrelated questions, e.g. how to prevent user to switch window (right?) on which windows system? x.org? But if you have access to low level system, why not installing freeBSD directly? An other thing it is not clear: do you want console or graphic environment? O

Comment: @Giacomo Catenazzi 
Thank you for your response.
I want console mode, because single-user-mode can fit 3 above-mentioned points.
With single-user-mode, only one thing I need to solve is "How to enable auto-login in single-user-mode".

Comment: @Giacomo Catenazzi 
And I guess that creating my own new single-user-mode runlevel could prevent from messing up the system.

Comment: Just to be clear. Console mode in Debian, right? I think you may setup console as serial console (so nobody will mess with it, and you can reboot changing the console, with boot barameters), and setup qemu to get directly keayboard and video memory. So, where is no way to switch back to debian (but with qemu bug, or by turning off the virtual env. The good: you should just learn few systems (qemu and your init system)

Comment: @Giacomo Catenazzi Yeah, console mode. Ok, I will try this. Thank you.